# displaying posts from a custom post type tags

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I created a custom post called projects and a taxonomy called tagportfolio ,
in the admin panel i created 3 tags under this taxonomy to filter my projects

[portfolio page](http://www.integritycorp.org/study/?page_id=34#all)

the three tags is

1. Urban planning and upgrading
2. Urban Design and Landscape
3. Architecture and Interior Design

under each tag there is a posts , now i need to know how i can display the posts that under each tag for example: posts under tag Architecture and Interior Design in a page template

Thanks

N.B this is the custom post and taxonomy functions 
git://gist.github.com/3066834.git gist-3066834

this is how the child tax should be displayed {like the main tax}
git://gist.github.com/3061479.git gist-3061479

Comment: Please add the code you used to create both (taxonomy and custom post type) to your question.

Comment: @ Toscho , i added in the question now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

```
echo '<ul>';

//The Arguments
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'project',
    'tagportfolio' => 'urban-design-and-landscape' //should use the slug name not the full name
);

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );


// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    echo '<li>';
    the_title();
    echo '</li>';
endwhile;

echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: not working thiago , i tried it :(

Comment: there was an spell error on my post_type argument. I have looked into your code and youre already using WP_Query, so you should do in the same way but adding your tagportifolio filter. http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

Comment: Also, if you havent yet, consider looking into [Child Themes](http://themeshaper.com/2009/04/17/wordpress-child-theme-basics/) topic, especially using thematic.